# Compare features of ES6 (compiled to ES5) vs CoffeeScript vs TypeScript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, ecmascript-6

We are going to start new project with frontend on JavaScript

But current state of JS (ES5) isn't cool enought, it misses a lot of cool features, thus now we are deciding what to choose:

1) write code in CoffeeScript and compile it

2) write code in ES6 and compile it using https://babeljs.io/

3) write code in TypeScript and compile it

Any suggestions? pros/cons?

Comment: Take a look at TypeScript - http://www.typescriptlang.org/ - It looks closer to ES6.

Comment: Thanks, forgot about it, but I personally don't like it, thus question why it's better than CoffeeScript or ES6

Comment: Of course its a matter of taste. If you're likely to move toward standards (like ES6), TypeScript feels more natural because it's syntax is just an extension of ES5. With CoffeeScript I feel like the JS developer needs to learn a somewhat-new language, which is not true for TS. I've also seen many successful usages of TS (including my own experience)

Comment: Tell us which cool features you are missing, then we can tell you which language to use. Otherwise this question is offtopic.

Answer (score 2):

It's hardly possible to say which is better.CoffeeScript and ES6 are really alike

**Both CoffeeScript and ES6 have**

- Classes
- string interpolation
- fat arrows
- function default arguments
- Variadic function
- Destructuring
- Splats

**CoffeeScript :**

- Pros

You can easily set instance variables in `Class`

```
class Person
  constructor : (@name,@age) ->
```

You can call functions without parentheses.

```
John = new Person "John",20
```

- Cons

Because CoffeeScript does NOT have `var`,whenever You want to define new variable,You have to always double check if the name's already defined at outer scope or not.This sometimes brings huge problem.

```
variableA = 123
doSomething = ->
  # You want to declare inner variable but Since same name's already exist,
  #it's gonna be substitution instead.
  variableA = "hello"
  return variableA
```

**ES6 :**

- Pros

ES6 Class has setter/getter

- Cons

It's not fully supported yet.So you have to always worry about things you can't and when you will be able to do them.

Comment: CS does not have getter/setter syntax? I can hardly believe.

Comment: good to know about the scoping issue, thank you